# Optimize splitting mysql_fetch_array results in to HTML sections

Tags: php, mysql

I am fetching an array of animal names, types, age, etc. from a MySQL DB. I want to divide these into sections for ages like so...

```
Ages 5 - 10
Dog named Brian
Cat named Kitty
Dog named Buster

Ages 10+
Cat named Moody
Dog named Milo
```

Here's how I am doing it right now (the query is already order by age):

```
while ($results = mysql_fetch_array($animals) {

if (($results[age] <= 10 && $results[age] >= 5) && !$head1 && !$head1display) {
    $head1 = 'Ages 5 to 10<br />';
    $head1display++;
} else $head1  = NULL;

if ($results[age] > 10 && !$head2 & !$head2display) {
    $head2 = 'Ages 10+<br />';
    $head2display++;
} else $head2  = NULL;  

echo $head1.$head2.$results[type].' named '.$results[name].'<br />';

}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Keep in mind I don't want to have two queries or two loops...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using doing grouping/ordering in your SQL to fetch the animals already in the right way, such as:

```
$sql = "select type, name, if(age<5, 'Ages <5', if(age<10, 'Ages 5 - 10', 'Ages 10+)) "heading"
        from animals
        order by age";
```

Then in you php you can do almost direct output:

```
$heading = '';
while ($results = mysql_fetch_array($animals) {
    if($results['heading'] != $heading) {
        $heading = $results['heading'];
        echo '<br/>' . $heading . '<br/>';
    }
    echo $results['type'].' named '.$results['name'].'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably easier to read using this method, but not sure how much its optimized. Also I assumed $result['name'] for the name of the animal

```
$younger = array();
$older = array();

while ($results = mysql_fetch_array($animals) {
    if ($results['age'] <= 10 && $results['age'] >= 5) {
        $younger[] = $result['type'].' named '.$result['name'];
    }

    if ($results['age'] > 10) {
        $older[] = $result['type'].' named '.$result['name'];
    }
}

if (count($younger)) {
    echo 'Ages 5 to 10<br />';
    join('<br />', $younger);
}

if (count($older)) {
    echo 'Ages 10+<br />';
    join('<br />', $older);
}
```

Comment: Hey Samura, no was working on it at the same time. Yours is simular but I would move $arr1 and $arr2 out of the while loop as they'll be reset on every iteration. Yours was definitely posted before mine and has the same logic pattern so if either was to be accepted it should be yours.

Comment: no. you're right. Mine has a huge mistake! Correcting anyway +1

Answer (score 0):

There were some errors in your code like:

```
$results[type].' named '.$results[type]
```

that I changed to:

```
$results[type].' named '.$results[name]
```

This only works if you have a `name` column in your database - change it accordingly.

```
$arr1 = array();
$arr2 = array();  
while ($results = mysql_fetch_array($animals)) {

  if ($results['age'] <= 10 && $results['age'] >= 5)
    $arr1[] =  $results['type'].' named '.$results['name'];
  elseif($results['age'] > 10)
    $arr2[] =  $results['type'].' named '.$results['name'];
}

echo (sizeof($arr1)) ? 'Ages 5 to 10<br />'. implode('<br/>', $arr1).'<br/>' : '' . (sizeof($arr2)) ? 'Ages 10+<br />'. implode('<br/>', $arr2).'<br/>' : '';
```

Comment: I like your use of arrays and printing outside the loop, however I feel like this is not totally optimized since there's duplication of printing twice...